# Error : Object are not valid as a React child in react native

Tags: react-native

Im developing an app in react native and I have an array called **users**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "occurrences": 42,
    "username": "teste0",
  },
  Object {
    "occurrences": 1,
    "username": "teste2",
  },
  Object {
    "occurrences": 5,
    "username": "teste1",
  },
  Object {
    "occurrences": 0,
    "username": "teste 3",
  },
]
```

when I try to put each username in a separate view

```
async function setUsersView() {
    let users;

    try {
      users = await listUserOcurrences(token);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    return users?.map((user) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.userView}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
            {"\n"} {users.username}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

I get the following error **Error : Object are not valid as a React child**

Answer (score 1):

users.username here it should be user.username, the callback for map is taking parameter user not users

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `setUsersView()` is `async` function, which not valid to rendering. Function should be pure function to render some view. So you can do like this :

First create a one state variable to check users is fetched or not, for ex:

```js
const [isLoadingUsers, setLoadingUserStatus] = useState(false); // functional component

// class component
this.state = {
  isLoadingUsers: false
}
```

Now, when you start fetching user toggle it's status to true and render the view based on it's value. For example if user is fetching then you can render `ActivityIndicator` or some placeholder and when it's complete the fetch displays the user.

```js
function setUsersView() {
  setLoadingUserStatus(true);
  let users;
  try {
    users = await listUserOcurrences(token);
    setLoadingUserStatus(false);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  if (isLoadingUsers) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.userView}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={true}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
  return users?.map((user) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.userView}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
          {"\n"} {users.username}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
}
```

Now, this is simple function and error will gone.

Comment: Ok understood. One more question, im not using classes is there any problem if I use the class component that u used above?

Comment: If you want to use class component then you have to modify state using  `this.setState({ isLoadingUsers: true})` instead of `setLoadingUserStatus(true);`.